# what view is this in android, I have seen this in iphone can any one help

Tags: android

what view is this in android, I have seen this in iphone can any one help[image]

the one shown in bottom near footer

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it is a custom view called `OperaSwView` only Opera has access to that view.

Comment: is there any thing that can be used to see this tiles type view or do we have to make custom gallary view

Comment: @SoftReference: It is a totally custom widget. You can inspect that layout yourself using the `hierarchyviewer` which is located in your `sdk/tools` directory.

Answer (score 2):

These are all custom views or a combination of multiple views or layouts, You can create one easily, Check out the following links

[Android UI](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)?